# Send data to a ws2801 LED strip with arduino

Tags: arduino, led

How do i send data manually (without any pre-made library) to a ws2801 led strip with a arduino?

I'm not asking for someone to write the code for me, just a push in the right direction.

i have a arduino leonardo

Comment: read the library, see how they do it, do it without the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use SPI, which is 3 data lines from the Arduino.

Check out this tutorial:
[Tronix SPI tutorial](http://tronixstuff.com/2011/05/13/tutorial-arduino-and-the-spi-bus/)

and then the Arduino library/tutorial:
[Arduino SPI Tutorial/Library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI)

Now check the datasheet and see what you can learn from it:
[WS2801 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/WS2801.pdf)

There are several video tutorials online about using the Arduino, check them out once you grok SPI it's really quite simple.:

Comment: The WS2801 does not use SPI.  It uses a 2-wire interface.

Answer (score 1):

The WS2801, does use a SPI type interface similar to a Shift register, you push 3 Bytes of data to populate the first chip, then keep pushing more Bytes for an overflow.

The Data Sheet shows two wire, Clock & Data; but you can also connect POL (Output polarity reversal) up to a PWM output for intensity, thus the 3-wire interface.

Look at [Adafruit-WS2801-Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-WS2801-Library) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This is several years later, but I'd been looking into the same subject, and found some relevant information that could help the next reader.

[This project by Josh Levine](https://wp.josh.com/2016/05/20/huge-scrolling-arduino-led-sign/)  uses 7 WS2812B strips to display scrolling text. The strips are connected in parallel to a single Arduino board, and the code for it does not use any pre-built library.

[Check out the code here](https://github.com/bigjosh/MacroMarquee/blob/master/Arduino/MacroMarquee/MacroMarquee.ino). The main thing is that the timing for WS2812b is very specific, and the code uses ASM to get the timing right. More reading about the WS2812 timing [here](https://wp.josh.com/2014/05/13/ws2812-neopixels-are-not-so-finicky-once-you-get-to-know-them/).

Additional reading: If you're interested in how the LED strips connected in parallel work, Josh has also written up an article explaining his bit-crunching technique for this, which you can [read here](https://wp.josh.com/2016/05/04/parallel-processing-arduino-style-make-massive-neopixel-displays-with-nanoscale-concurrent-computing/).

Comment: Wow, that's impressive! I'm actually looking into making a similar LED display atm so thanks for linking it :)